# How to select specific column ranges in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of the form:

**df**

```
    0    1    2    3    ..    60    61    62    63    ..    420
0   A    C    B    F          B      C    A      A           F
1   B    A    C    E          F      E    B      C           A
2   A    F    E    B          C      F    F      A           C
```

I want to return a dataframe with the following columns 0:19, 60:79, 360:379.

What is the most efficient way of going about this?

Comment: One way or other you need to construct a list or array of the desired columns.  That's a one time task, and small compared to the job of loading the file.  So don't worry about efficiency (expect maybe your own typing time).

Comment: you can try `columns_list = list(range(0,20))+list(range(60,80))+list(range(360,380))
df[df.columns[columns_list]]`